# How to convert JavaScript array into usable format for creating a poly line

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Begin Edit**
A summary of my problem is I have some data in a javascript file in this format:

```
var coords = [y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x];
```

The x's are y's are coordinates and are paired in the order they are listed in the file. I need to try and get them into this format

```
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [
 new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
 new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
 new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
 new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
 ];
```

So that I can use them to create a polyline as in this exampler [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove).

Hope this helps and thank you so much for looking into this.

Sincerely,
Fredk
**End Edit**

I am trying to creating a single page application that will display a map using the google map javascipt api v3. I would like to include a polyline on my map. I have many coordinates that need to go into that polyline so I am trying to write a function that can use the data I have and convert it into a usable form for the google map api can read to build my polyline with.
[Here is a link to the google api page where I received that source code I have been modifying.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove)

Below is a copy of my map.js file that I have modified :

```
var flightPath;
var map;
var xCoords = [];
var yCoords = [];        
var i;
var j;
var pair = [];
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.439346,-86.88312500000001),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var coordinates = [-86.86975061322778,33.45022772942718,0 -86.86983081545476,33.44984709324155,0 -86.8698489609808,33.44972050194397,0 -86.86984514868711,33.44957326614615,0 -86.86986831806067,33.44945663523548,0 -86.86988032018508,33.44933971655625,0 -86.86987767688218,33.44933538273567,0 -86.86985346069216,33.44926927479551,0 -86.86986610347115,33.44915520689104,0 -86.86987403521013,33.44909614577527,0 -86.87000166115789,33.44913075253221,0 -86.87006933561028,33.44913077797188,0 -86.87020144056702,33.44912059996341,0 -86.87037409276223,33.44909566406788,0 -86.87050920030728,33.44907279547318,0 -86.87056967910343,33.44906069346168,0 -86.87064517640975,33.44905301035505,0 -86.87066506563541,33.44905763617184,0 -86.87070559474269,33.44904079277664,0 -86.87112477907611,33.44879061812004,0 -86.87127714823728,33.44868441478428,0 -86.87133831092851,33.44862255914364,0 -86.87140829509003,33.44856066110657,0 -86.87160009010373,33.44852059950046,0 -86.87177381495617,33.44852885327281,0 -86.8718301146428,33.44853226046898,0 -86.87183530028184,33.44850711755228,0 -86.87181601728712,33.4484921764092,0 -86.87178381435213,33.44847478536339,0 -86.87176815693098,33.44847361441725,0 -86.87170865889149,33.44844433307853,0 -86.87165866194815,33.44841835989084,0 -86.87163277565037,33.44838974773397,0 -86.87160506943319,33.44833412435006,0 -86.87160937360066,33.44831453017596,0 -86.8716225021317,33.44828365572863,0 -86.87169370199757,33.44823222790846,0 -86.87173270895835,33.44821186026292,0 -86.87177013275485,33.44820796953973,0 -86.87184415685101,33.44818735703936,0 -86.871869569778,33.4481511439548,0 -86.87186292650776,33.44812763854002,0 -86.87183464441262,33.44811319128804,0 -86.87175085693765,33.44796655620282,0 -86.87165115638439,33.4477646420685,0 -86.86991597400394,33.44592231552179,0 -86.8696875427883,33.44577012473676,0 -86.86949455487714,33.4456781129633,0 -86.86931261173804,33.44567309377634,0 -86.86910291206763,33.44574427950384,0 -86.86904316532795,33.44570799260179,0 -86.86903785312185,33.44570790754563,0 -86.86902051276523,33.44567222884994];

for (i = 0,j=0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
     yCoords[j] = coordinates[i];
    ++i;
    xCoords[j] = coordinates[i];
    pair[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(xCoords[j], yCoords[j]);
    ++j;  
};
    console.log(pair);

  flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: pair,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
  });

  addLine();
}

function addLine() {
flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function removeLine() {
flightPath.setMap(null);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

Here is my html file associated with displaying the map:

```
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove line">
      <input onclick="addLine();" type=button value="Restore line">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>

   <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove line">
      <input onclick="addLine();" type=button value="Restore line">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
```

This is the log of the console.log(pair); on line 27 of map.js:

```
[hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf, hf]
```

.

When you click on the hf's to dig deeper you realize that they contain they data assigned during the for loop that begins on line 20 of map.js. I am not receiving any errors when I am inspecting in chrome and the map is displaying , but it is not drawing the polyline. Thank you for your time in advance.

Sincerely,

-Fredk

Comment: Is there any chance you can summarise your question to say "Here is the array format I'm starting with: `[x,y,z]` and here is the array format that I need: `[/*whatever*/]`? Because then we can help you with code to do the transformation without having to go off and read Google's documentation and so forth...

Comment: Your array doesn't make sense.  it looks like coordinates that came out of KML (longitude, latitude, altitude tuples, separated by spaces; which is not a valid javascript array).  To create a google.maps.Polyline, it needs to be an array of google.maps.LatLng objects.

Comment: Yes I can summarize that is a much better idea thank you one second. The summary will be posted above.

Comment: Cool. Although have a look at the answer below, which seems to be saying the array isn't the problem.

Comment: Hey I tried to provide a good summary to help make it more comprehensive. I am sorry I was so vague. Hope that helps and thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Line is being displayed by the map , you just cant see it**

you have set map's center to (33.439346,-86.88312500000001) ,  but if you console and check your pair array, the lat and long coordinates are swapped

pair[0] gives me :  lat=-86.86975061322778, long=33.45022772942718

anyways, if you wanna see your polyline , just throw this piece of code into your addLine() function :
map.panTo(pair[0]);

your polyline is outside the map bounds, thats it.

Comment: I am assuming that there is nothing wrong with the HTML,
I see two body Tags with same content??????
and i am also assuming you have set height and width of map-canvas DIV in the CSS...

Comment: Yes man thank you @Shashank Indian you were correct. Thank you everyone for looking into this for me.